# Can an IDE/Netbeans connect to a remote computer and compile/run/debug code on it?

Tags: c++, netbeans, development-environment, remote-access

I'm developing a program for a specific environment. That means it needs to run on the OS and compile using its compiler. I have a different environment at home (Windows 8) is there a way Netbeans can be used to connect to the target environment and use its compiler? It is enabled for remote login.

So basically right now I write code on my home computer, connect using Putty to the target computer, copy the source code over, compile it and run it. I'm trying to simplyfy this process so I only have to use Netbeans.

Why don't I just get same compiler and do everything locally? The target computer is running Linux and the program has a lot of system calls.

I know Aptana has a simillar feature, but Aptana is so crappy in general I don't want to use it.

Let me know if my question doesn't make sense and I'll try and reword it.

Comment: Not sure about Netbeans, but I use [STAF](http://staf.sourceforge.net/) for pretty much all my remote needs, which would be able help you copy, compile, and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do remote development in NetBeans. It's described in its Help subsystem:

[image: NetBeans help screen]